# ID of new item in Kendo UI data source

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui

When I create a new item in the server-side [using a Kendo UI data source](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transport-object), **how do I update the ID of the client-side data item** with the ID of the new record inserted in the database in the server-side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing more research I have found this extremely useful information which, indeed, should be in the docs, but it is "hidden" in a not-so-easy-to-find forum search message:

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/refresh-grid-after-datasource-sync.aspx#2124402

I am not sure if this is the best approach, but it resolved my problem!

This solution simply uses the data source **read** method to update the model instances with data from server.

The precious info is **where** it is done: in the "**complete**" event of the **transport.create** object!

Here is the code:

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "http://myurl.json"
    },
    create: {
        url: "http://mycreate.json",
        type: "POST",
        complete: function(e) {
            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read(); 
        }
    },
```

Comment: But then every single time that you create a new item you go to the database, save it, and then once you come back you go to the database again to read the information that you already had. Its redundant, there must be a way to update the view. Btw, are you Brazilian?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the additional server call introduced by the read method, if you have your create method return an object the Data Source will automaticly insert it for you.

Knowing that all you need to do is set the id field from the database and return the model.

e.g. psudo code for ASP MVC action for create.

```
public JsonResult CreateNewRow(RowModel rowModel)
{
    // rowModel.id will be defaulted to 0

    // save row to server and get new id back
    var newId = SaveRowToServer(rowModel);

    // set new id to model
    rowModel.id = newId;

    return Json(rowModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and think I may have found the answer. If in the schema you define the object that holds the results, you must return the result of the created link in that same object. Example:

```
schema: {
          data: "Results",
          total: "ResultsCount", .... 
}
```

Example MVC method:

```
public JsonResult CreateNewRow(RowModel rowModel)
{
    // rowModel.id will be defaulted to 0

    // save row to server and get new id back
    var newId = SaveRowToServer(rowModel);

    // set new id to model
    rowModel.id = newId;

    return Json(new {Results = new[] {rowModel}});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Jack's answer (I don't have the reputation to comment), if your Create and Update actions return data with the same schema as defined in the kendo DataSource, the DataSource will automatically update the Id field as well as any other fields that may have been modified by the action call.  You don't have to do anything other that form your results correctly.  I use this feature to calculate a bunch of stuff on the server side and present the client with the results w/o requiring a complete reload of the data.